# Differentiating between multiple clients when multiple services are running in SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, client, signalr, signalr.client

I have a **Windows Service** written in **C#** that uses **SignalR** to self-host for each respective client. This windows service will receive some parameters from a C# **MVC Web Application** that will be retrieved via the `Send()` method in the `MyHub` class. I'm parsing out the `message` variable and doing things with it. So it looks something like this:

**MyCustomService.cs**

```
public partial class MyCustomService: ServiceBase
{
    private IDisposable SignalR;
    public MyCustomService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventLog1 = new EventLog();
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";

    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service started.");
        string url = "http://localhost:8080";
        SignalR = WebApp.Start(url);
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server running on " + url);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry(LogMessage.Message);
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Service stopped");
        SignalR.Dispose();
    }

}
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}

public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);

        // Do other stuff that is omitted for brevity   

    }
}
```

My web application running will send data from the server side to the client's local PC via the windows service shown above - when a user presses the **Send** button.

**MyWebApp.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>

    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            //Set the hubs URL for the connection
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;

            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };

            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));

            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();

            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What will happen is that MyCustomService will eventually be installed on multiple computers that are connected to the *same* network. So:

Computer A **has** a instance of MyCustomService running on http://localhost:8080

Computer B **has** a instance of MyCustomService running on http://localhost:8080

Computer C **has** a instance of MyCustomService running on http://localhost:8080

The problem is this:

> How can I differentiate between *clients*? Will the multiple instances of MyCustomService conflict since they are all on the same network?

For example: If **Computer A** clicks the **Send** button, I don't want **Computer B** to do anything with that data but since Computer B's service is looking at http://localhost:8080 it will receive that information and will also have its own instance of it even know technically they will all be the same.

I want to be able to say:

**Computer A** has pressed **Send** then do stuff in the windows service running on Computer A

Tell the duplicate service running in Computer C "dont do anything your Computer C not Computer A!"

Tell the duplicate service running in Computer B "dont do anything your Computer B not Computer A!"

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` is translated to loacal ip adress so ComputerA call own ip and ComputerB call own, different ip.

Comment: Is that **always** the case though?

Comment: Yes. Read [this](https://whatismyipaddress.com/localhost).

Comment: So http://localhost:8080 will point to the *internal* address or *external* address?

Comment: Form article: "The localhost is the default name describing the local computer address also known as the loopback address. For example, typing: ping localhost would ping the local IP address of 127.0.0.1 (the loopback address). When setting up a web server or software on a web server, 127.0.0.1 is used to point the software to the local machine."

Comment: So let me follow up with this question: When someone opens up my web url www.I'mAFakeWebsite.com and they click the Send button - as long as they have MyCustomService running , that service should activate and retrieve data right? Or will it be different? Is the server side code looking for localhost on the **server** or on the client's machine now is the question.. (see the html / js code above)

Comment: localhost is **always** machine on which code runs. For server side code is server for js is browser machine. So if you have on same computer js and server it must work.

Comment: I *think* I understand what you are saying. I'm going to do a little bit more testing